# Deserialization of a protobuf object in Corda

Tags: java, corda, hedera-hashgraph

I am trying to instantiate and sign a protobuf message within a Corda flow; the original transaction is created by a JavaScript client, encoded as base64, and submitted to Corda. The Corda node decodes, signs and forwards to the public network.

The transaction, signing, and approval works fine (it actually executes in the Public Network), but upon returning the result it fails with the attached error.

Is there any mechanism to deserialize the protobuf transaction without breaking the [FiberDeserializationChecker]?

Thank you in advance!

```
Thu Mar 25 16:43:10 UTC 2021>>> on: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Deserialization via serialization delegate
Serialization trace:
validStart (com.hedera.hashgraph.sdk.TransactionId)
transactionIds (com.hedera.hashgraph.sdk.TokenAssociateTransaction)
associateTxn (net.aochain.corda.nodes.hederaTxn.AssociateTokenFlow)
logic (net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:144)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:145)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813)
        at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readClassAndObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:112)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731)
        at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:92)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:145)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731)
        at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:92)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:145)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731)
        at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:92)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:543)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber$FiberSerializer.read(Fiber.java:2156)
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber$FiberSerializer.read(Fiber.java:2086)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813)
        at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readClassAndObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:112)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$deserialize$1$1.invoke(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:92)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$deserialize$1$1.invoke(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:42)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoStreams.kryoInput(KryoStreams.kt:20)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$deserialize$1.invoke(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:81)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$deserialize$1.invoke(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:42)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$kryo$1.execute(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:70)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:58)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer.kryo(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:66)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer.deserialize(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:80)
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.interceptors.FiberDeserializationChecker$start$2.invoke(FiberDeserializationCheckingInterceptor.kt:103)
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.interceptors.FiberDeserializationChecker$start$2.invoke(FiberDeserializationCheckingInterceptor.kt:53)
        at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:30)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Deserialization via serialization delegate
        at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.getReplacement(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:129)
        at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readReplace(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:118)
        at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readObjectOrNull(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:107)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:132)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Deserialization via serialization delegate
        at org.threeten.bp.Instant.readResolve(Instant.java:1176)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.getReplacement(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:125)
```

Comment: I've forwarded this to some friends at R3 who can hopefully help out.

Answer (score 0):

From Matt Nesbit @R3 :

> Their flow checkpoint is including objects that aren't kryo (de)serialisable. Most probably they need to hide any statics/native methods behind a SingletonSerialiseAsToken derived object probably held by a CordaService.
>
> That probably includes their protobuf serialiser, but from this little info could be anything, since they appear to be also including Hedera Hashgraph

if you could share some more info or msg me on slack.corda.net I could help with getting you some more info

Comment: Thank you. Getting now to Slack!

Answer (score 0):

Matt and David reply send me through the right path.

You have to create a new class as described [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/api-service-classes.html#tabs-1-java). In our case, the deserializer event is included into an API, and that blocks the read from Kyro when the (de)serialization happens.

Thank you both!